# Cannot center buttons on horizontal nav bar

Tags: html, css

I've spent an absurd amount of time on google and still cannot figure out how to center the buttons on my nav bar (I'm still new to css).

Here is what I have for the navbar (not included are my various failed attempts).

## CSS:

```
#navigation
{
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #222222;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
}

#navigation li
{
    border-right: solid 1px #ca0002;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation li a:link, #navigation li a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;  
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    border-right: solid 1px #990000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#navigation li a:hover
{
    background: #990000;
    color: #fff;
}

#navigation li.first
{
    border-left: solid 1px #ca0002;
}
```

Comment: We need the HTML as well if you want us to make a Fiddle.

Comment: Do you want *all* of the buttons to be in the center?

Comment: You should really include your HTML

Comment: `margin: left auto;` isn't proper CSS. You can condense all the "navigation" CSS to `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any html I took the liberty of creating the html and using your IDs.

Here is a working fiddle:

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewJamesMP/XeBF9/)

In your navigation div I added

```
    height: auto; 
    text-align:center;
```

Some unnecessary CSS was deleted as well.

This will make the navigation tabs center in the div.

Hope this helps!